# get post jquery and echo it in $_POST(is that possible?)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm learning how to post data to server.I want to click on a link and post its data to the server in the same page, do I need to have a form to do that? is it possible to post data without having a form?   I cannot see the result in php should I have any success or done function here to have the results? I also have tried Last example of [Jquery manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and there is no content div to see any results and so I couldn't figure it out.

I do not want to show data and append it in the html I want to see it in $_POST and if it is not possible to show it in the same page I am ok with that all I want is to see $_POST can have the data from JQUERY

```
 <?php 
if(isset($_POST["name"]))
echo $_POST["name"];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#link").click(function(){
            $.post("newfile5.php",
            {
              name: $("#link").val()
            }


        });
$('form#myform').submit();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myform" action="newfile5.php" method="POST">
<a id="link" href="" value="A">Send</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PS:I updated upon answers, and still not result:

```
 <?php 
if(isset($_POST["name"]))
echo $_POST["name"];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#link").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("newfile5.php",
        {
          name: $("#link").data("value")
        },
        function(data)
        {
            // Whatever is returned by newfile5.php
        }

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="link" href="" data-value="A">Send</a>

</body>
</html>
```

I expect to see $_POST['name'] having the value A, just this

Answer (score 0):

Use `data-attr` to store data.

```
<a id="link" href="" data-value="A">Send</a>
```

Use

```
console.log($("#link").data("value"));
```

to fetch it.

So your code becomes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#link").click(function(e){
        $("#disp_name").html($("#link").data("value"));
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("newfile5.php",
        {
          name: $("#link").data("value")
        },
        function(resp)
        {
             console.log(resp); // Whatever is returned by newfile5.php
        }

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="disp_name"></div>
<form id="myform" action="newfile5.php" method="POST">
<a id="link" href="" data-value="A">Send</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and dont use  `$('form#myform').submit();`

and to fetch data in PHP, use

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
```

Comment: I added `e.preventDefault();` removed `$('form#myform').submit();` and also  the `data-value` is accessible. And for one more change see the updated one.

Comment: I copy pasted your code I am not seeing any result I don't know where the problem is

Comment: What results are you expecting? Is your PHP echoing something? Then check your console or replace `console.log` with `alert`

Comment: I expect to see the echo $_POST["name"];

Comment: this is the code that I posted I want to get the name from the post of jquery and show it in $_POST['name']

Comment: No @Nickparsa, It wont be shown on the same page. If you want to see in the same page at the top then please see the updated answer.

Comment: well you are answering other question I want to see it in php not in html I already know it how in the html but not   in $_POST I don't care if it is not the same page I just want to see it in $_POST just tell me how

Comment: Why are you using AJAX then, Just use simple HTML and PHP.

Comment: I already know how to use html and php I want to post to jquery and have result so that I can do some other functions with the result like keeping the data without session and these sort of stuff

Comment: Then your `newfile5.php` should have code like `echo $_POST["name"]`, then you can see that it's logged in console after the AJAX is success.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to click on a link and post its data to the server in the same page, do I need to have a form to do that?

No. You can post the data without having a form.

---

**EDIT**

To answer the question after edit (if I well understand it):

Seems to me actually like a X-Y problem but the answer is - **No** .

PHP isn't able to interfere with the client browser. The AJAX is only a "bridge" between the server (PHP) and the page that has been fully rendered.
(you may want to read about [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket))

Fully rendered page have no access to the PHP  variables anymore (doesn't matter if it's jQuery or any other client-side language). When connection to the server is completed (page fully rendered), all the PHP named variables and methods cease to exist. They could be set only at the time when the page is being rendered (and that's the only way to get these two languages to work together at the same time), eg:

```
<script>
    var myData = "<?php echo 'something'; ?>";
</script>
```

Basically, the `$.post` is used to communicate with the server. If that's not required, you can access the data within the page itself and `$.post` is not even necessary.

You have an trigger event (click). You set the event to determine when an action should be taken and what is supposed to happen then. Whether it's an AJAX request or anything else.

If the AJAX is required:

```
var myData = '';
$("#link").click(function(e){
    $.post(
        "newfile5.php",
        {name: $("#link").attr('value')},
        function( data ) {
            myData = data;
            doSomething();
            // do something else with the data here. ...
        }
    );
});
```

If there's no need to post any data:

```
var myData;
$("#link").click(function(e){
    myData = $("#link").attr('value');
    doSomething();
});
```

The method:

```
function doSomething(){
    if(myData){
       alert(myData);
   }else{
       // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: and do what on success?

Comment: I removed my form submit but still I am not seeing the value

Comment: philip, I tested. I am not seeing anything in the alert nor in $_POST which should be shown

Comment: Try it now. changed `val()` to `$("#link").attr('value')`

Comment: can we see the $_POST["name"] in the page? is that possible to see?I am not seeing it I am seeing the data alert

Comment: what does `<?php 
     if(isset($_POST["name"])){
        exit( trim($_POST["name"]) );
     }
 ?>` of the code doing here?

Comment: Yes, add an element where the data is supposed to be displayed, then use `$(element).html(data);`

Comment: philip I know how to get it in html my question is $_POST

Comment: `exit` prevents displaying the whole page in ajax response. If the $_`POST['name']` exists, PHP echoes only the data and exit the app immediately after that. Otherwise the whole page will be returned as ajax response

Comment: so I should suppose my answer to this question is NO it is NOT possible to show the $_POST result from jquery

Comment: I don't really get your point... The answer was for the main question (before you edit it) I supposed you can't get the ajax response.

Answer (score -1):

in php access the `$_POST` variable

Edit:

First of all, you are combining two different ways and doing them wrong at the same time. You are making an AJAX request, and then sending a normal HTTP request without a value. Both wrongs, try this example, it will make an Ajax Post Request and show you the result in an Alert.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["name"]))
echo $_POST["name"];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#link").click(function(){
            $.post("newfile5.php",
            {
              name: 'Some Name'
            }, function(data) {
                alert(data)
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myform" action="newfile5.php" method="POST">
<a id="link" href="" value="A">Send</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean? I have $_POST in the top

Comment: Didn't saw the PHP snippet, your problem is that the way you are trying to post the data is incorrect, I will update my answer.